# Search every field or attribute in model Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have a simple model called Company with atributes such as Name, contact email, address, etc.  I've created a search form where a user can find the company by searching for any attribute i.e., city, name of business, etc.

I'm new to Rails but I've figured out how to get it working like so in my controller.

```
    if(params[:searchstring].present?)
          logger.debug "*** Running search --> "
          term = params[:searchstring]
          @companies = Company.where('name LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR contactemail LIKE ? OR city LIKE ?' , "%#{term}%", "%#{term}%", "%#{term}%","%#{term}%" ).paginate(page: params[:page]).order('id DESC')    
        else
          logger.debug "*** Running search --> get em all "
          @companies = Company.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).order('id DESC')    
        end
end
```

This works fine but I'm guessing there is a much simplier way.  I'd prefer not to modify the query every time I add an attribute.  Any ideas on how to improve this?

Comment: You could maybe just iterate through Company.column_names, wich return an array of the properties, and then build your query string?

That might be slower but will fill your need.

Comment: Any suggestions/code on how to do that?  Sounds like a good idea and I'd be curious to see it as I'm new to Ruby/RoR.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with something like this (It is just an example, might be a better way, but it is fonctionnal)

```
# company.rb
def self.search_all_properties term 
    query = ''
    properties = Company.column_names
    properties.each_with_index do |prop, index|
        if index < properties.count - 1
            query = query + prop + ' LIKE :term OR '
        else
            query = query + prop + ' LIKE :term'
        end
    end

    term = "%" + term + "%"
    Company.where(query, :term => term) 
end
```

and use it like this

```
Company.search_all_properties term
```